# Can't declare variable in function MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm newbie in SQL and trying to create function in MS SQL 2008R2, but can't declare variable inside function. What's wrong with this code?

```
CREATE FUNCTION denominator() RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count;
    -- Some logic here
END;

GO
SELECT dbo.denominator()

DROP FUNCTION denominator
```

I'm getting that kind of errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure denominator, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.denominator", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Comment: Why you aren't using postgres or mysql dbs? I think it gives huge profit for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to write like this , data type of variable is missing

```
DECLARE @Count int;
```

Answer (score 2):

you're declaring of `@Count` has no data type, you should provide it.

```
DECLARE @Count int
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable @Count doe not have a data type.Use this:

```
Declare @Count int
```

Don't forget to add the **RETURN** keyword in the function